# Forms Authentication Login timeout does not work

Tags: asp.net, forms, authentication, timeout

ASP.Net 4.0 application, using Forms Authentication, timeout="1". The redirect page is Login.aspx.

As soon as I log into the application, I am taken into a default page (Page A), and if I wait idle for 1 minute and then try to access another page (Page B), I am re-directed to the login page (correctly).

If however, as soon as I log in, I access Page B and wait idle for 1 minute and then try to perform some other postback action, I am allowed to do so (where as I should be thrown back to the Login.aspx)

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Are you sure you are waiting the full 1 min?  Can you try clearing your cookies just before the postback and see if that works?

Comment: Yes, I am timing myself; you mean clear the cookies from the browser?

Comment: Yes.  That will insure the cookie is destroyed and you should be redirected to login when the postback occurs. How do you get to Page B from Page A?  Is it a hyperlink or redirect after postback?  If it's the later, they Page B might not be under the FA restricted area (for example, in a different folder not secured by FA).

Comment: The redirection is from the menu which is bound to the web.sitemap file. PageB is not under the same folder as PageA; how can I know whether the folder PageB is in is under FA or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the all the required folders are managed by FA...

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms name=".AUTH_COOKIE" loginUrl="~/login.aspx" protection="All" timeout="2880" requireSSL="false"/>
    </authentication>
</system.web>
```

Then, just after the system.web element of the web.config, add as many of these entries as are required to secure folders (remember, leave out the initial forward slash - all paths are absolute by default)...

```
<location path="securefolder">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?"/>
            <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

EDIT:

Keep in mind that sub folders of secured folders are secured by default - the allows the specification of multiple folders that are not nested.